# How to create a custom viewModel provider class where i can avoid the viewModel cast?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, viewmodelproviders

Good Morning ;

I have this custom ViewModel factory class:

```
class AlreadyHaveAnAccountFragmentViewModelFactory (private val userDataSourceRepository: UserDataSourceRepository) :
ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return AlreadyHaveAnAccountViewModel(userDataSourceRepository) as T
  }
}

    /**
     * Initializing our ViewModel using a custom Factory design pattern
     */
    alreadyHaveAnAccountViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(
        this,
        AlreadyHaveAnAccountFragmentViewModelFactory(
            RepositoryFactory.createApiRepository()
        )
    ).get(AlreadyHaveAnAccountViewModel::class.java)
```

The function create returns **AlreadyHaveAnAccountViewModel(userDataSourceRepository)** where **AlreadyHaveAnAccountViewModel** is my viewModel class. 
I need to create a custom viewModel factory class where i can pass **AlreadyHaveAnAccountViewModel** in parameter, or a way to avoid the nasty cast in the end.

help

Comment: I am not really sure what you want to do, custom ViewModelFactory with parameter your ViewModel (AlreadyHaveAnAccountViewModel)? Why you need this?

Comment: using this methode i need to create a new ViewModelProvider each time i create a new ViewModel, i want to create a custom viewModel where i can use it with any viewModel in my project

Comment: i want to  avoid the nasty cast in the end :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
With this methode you can avoid the cast in the end. This way you have only one ViewModelProvider in all your project.

This will work with any class accepting a UserDataSourceRepository as constructor argument and will throw NoSuchMethodException if the class doesn't have the proper constructor.

```
class AlreadyHaveAnAccountFragmentViewModelFactory (private val userDataSourceRepository: UserDataSourceRepository) :
ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return modelClass.getConstructor(UserDataSourceRepository::class.java).newInstance(userDataSourceRepository) as T
  }
}
```